# MariaDB error: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 12: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, mariadb

I have KVM VDS on CentOS 7 with hhvm, nginx and MariaDB, with few static sites (pure html/css) and one php site with a DB (actually Wordpress). This night I received notifications from the uptime tracker, static sites were down for about 40 minutes, and WP site was down until morning when I restarted MariaDB manually. Having done that, I checked the logs and it appeared tables needed repair.

The night's log sequence:

```
171231 17:03:26 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.56-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
180128 01:59:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
180128  1:59:04 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.56-MariaDB) starting as process 1150 ...
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180128  1:59:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
180128  1:59:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180128  1:59:05 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.52-MariaDB-38.3 started; log sequence number 18372705
180128  1:59:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180128  1:59:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
180128  1:59:05 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 12: Cannot allocate memory
180128  1:59:05 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
180128  1:59:05 [ERROR] Aborting

180128  1:59:05  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180128  1:59:09  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 18372705
180128  1:59:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

180128 01:59:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
180128 09:39:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

I would like to know, what could have happened, is it my fault for not having configured something properly or is it my hoster's fault? What else should I check?

Comment: Check your innodb configuration settings. MariaDB, at least my in experience, is notorious for having cryptic error messages in some instances.